# Can i "add module" to unity editor that download without unity hub?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I downloaded unity editor from unity download archive but now i need the android build support module "also known as android SDK/NDK tools" but the "add module" button missing from hub is there is anyway to fix it or if there is a way to download modules without hub Please help Unity hub 2.4.5 Unity editor 2019.2.9

Comment: You need to install directly from unityhub to add modules, i think so

Comment: Inside your Unity installation in the Build settings there should be a direct button for downloading and installing only the Android build support and according embedded SDK/NDK

Comment: @JustARandomWibuuuu it needs to be installed vis the Hub in order to add modules via the Hub .. you can still add modules the "old" way without the hub

Comment: hmm, i think it the archive version will be provided with the environment, there is some tricky things i dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, android build support module in unity is totally different from SDK/NDK/JDK tools

**if you want to install the build support module using one of blew steps:
1- instead of downloading the unity Editor download the unity installer from [this link](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive)(you can find all versions of unity and download the right installer), and choose the modules you need to install

2- easiest way is to open *build setting* in unity and choose the android from the platform section,if you don't have the module, you will see a button that says open download page, and you can simply download and install the module after clicking that button[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooTFn.png).

**normally when you install the android build support it will install the dependencies automatically, but if there was a problem you can manually download the tools(SDK/NDK/JDK) and use the manual on [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html) to tell the unity to use your custom tools.

SDK: the easiest way to install the android studio
NDK: download r19 version [this link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases#ndk-19c-downloads)
JDK: download jdk8 from [this link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8-windows)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you use the archive Unity version? You should use the latest versions.
Second, if you really need to use this version and there is no add modules button, the easiest (and I think the only one) is to download Android Studio, then install the needed SDK/NDK and then provide the path in Unity Editor (Preferences -> External Tools) to it.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has to make it easier for older versions to add modules. meanwhile, there are different ways to approach, the best of which is to get the `modules.json` file for your Unity version from [this repo](https://github.com/Larusso/unity-version-manager/tree/master/commands/uvm-generate-modules-json/tests/fixures) and look for the specific files you're after, and then follow the instructions in the modules. (for example they might suggest to rename the file after download)